# Ajax request returns failure

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have written a small script to make an Ajax request. I use jQuery for this purpose. I have done this several times but this is the first time I get a failure message. This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnExecute").click(function(){
        var numberOfClusters = $('#inputNumCab').val();
        alert(numberOfClusters);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'RunPythonThroughPHP/insertData_2.php',
            //data: { numberOfClusters: numberOfClusters },
            success: function(msg){
                alert('thanks');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
       });
    });
});
```

The concept is the following. When I press the button (which is in a form) I get the value of a text field (based on id) and I pass this data into my ajax request. The problem is I get the failure alert. 
Why this happens? If I make my request not async (async: false) then it works.

Comment: This happens when the server responds with a HTTP code of anything other than `200`. This means that the error is in your `insertData_2.php` file. You need to either check the network tab to find the error message (or check your server logs) and debug that script, not the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can it be also that my form button is type of submit? Should it be another type?

Comment: In that case best practice is to hook to the `submit()` event of the `form`, however it wouldn't affect the AJAX request. You still have an issue in your PHP.

Comment: The button `type` attribute shouldn't affect anything, but `name = "submit"` sometimes does. But that doesn't look like the issue - as others have said, check your PHP file.

Comment: Nope! That was it. When I changed the <input id="btnExecute" type="submit".. /> to <input id="btnExecute" type="button"../> it worked.

Comment: But I guess changing the type from submit to button is not a good practice or?

Comment: perhaps you need to prevent the form actually submitting?

Comment: You can prevent by using jq preventDefault, or return false in a function that is called by submit

Comment: It sounds like there might be a few separate things going on, but I think they were mostly addressed in the comments above... however one more minor thing that I noticed, is that in your example you have the data parameter commented out. As is, insertData_2.php will not get a value for numberOfClusters. Perhaps that PHP script requires that value to be set (and resulting in a non-200 return status)?